# HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(Urlstring) not working- Page not found error

Tags: asp.net

I am using HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode for encode url. when hit encoded url result is page not found

HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("http://example.com/Fundamentals of Data Structures C++")

Encoded Url

http://example.com/Fundamentals%20Of%20Data%20Structures%20C++

Page not found

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Does the page open correctly if you go to `"http://example.com/Fundamentals of Data Structures C++"`? If yes, look into your routing settings.

Comment: i am using URL routing. If going with http:example.com/Fundamentals of Data Structures C++ still page not found error. if go with encoded url without any special char then works fine

Comment: "without any special char" you mean without `++` at the end?

Comment: Please check live  
  
`http://www.booksbecho.in/Operation%20System%20Concepts%208Th%20Edition?Id=1948427714`

`http://www.booksbecho.in/Fundamentals%20Of%20Data%20Structures%20C++?Id=1197287199`

Answer (score 0):

The `+` sign is a special sign in URLs. It's used to represent a space. You should Encode the `+` sign. It's value should be `%2B`. E.g. `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(someURL).Replace("+","%2B")`

Comment: No luck still same `http://www.booksbecho.in/Fundamentals%20Of%20Data%20Structur‌​es%20C%2B%2B?Id=11972871‌​99`

Comment: OK. It seems like your routing settings just ignore the `+` signs in URLs. `http://www.booksbecho.in/Fundamentals%20Of%20Data%20Structures%20C?Id=1197287199` So use the following: `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(someURL).Replace("+","")`

Comment: BTW, check your search too. E.g. if I search for `C++` it breaks `http://www.booksbecho.in/all-india/all-categories/1/c%2B%2B` Make sure you remove `+` signs from there too.

Comment: Thank you.it works now. But what if other special char used in url instead of +?